# Could not find type or namespace name 'ImportFilesr'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I want to write the data in the ini file, so I wrote an 'ImportFilesr' class, but I changed the name of this class twice in the middle.
Later I found out that every time I run this program, the Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition will report an error 'Could not find type or namespace name 'ImportFilesr'

Here is my 'ImportFilesr':

```
  public class ImportFilesr
  {
   public string FileName; 
   string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, ”01.ini“);
   [DllImport("kernel32")]
   private static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val,     string filePath);
   [DllImport("kernel32")]
   private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def,      byte[] retVal, int size, string filePath);

...

   IniFiles()
   {
       UpdateFile();
   }
}
```

Has anyone had the same experience? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `ImportFilesr` class defined in the code displayed here. The code shown here also has other problems, like invalid characters ("curly quotes").

Comment: Does your file include a namespace declaration at all? Either `namespace ImportFilesr { public class IniFiles { } }` or `namespace ImportFilesr; public class IniFiles { }`?

Comment: Sorry this is the code before I changed it, I have changed the class name over.

Comment: This is still code that wouldn't compile - you've got a constructor expecting to be in an `IniFiles` class, but it's declared in `ImportFilesr`. You also haven't shown any code that tries to reference it. And your string literal has invalid quotes. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1. Click on that error in the exception list to view the corresponding line of code
2. Press alt+enter to see if there is a namespace that can be applied
3. Or directly refer to the namespace where ImportFilesr is located
4. Use Visual Studio Installer to repair Visaul Studio

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have that problem is because you did not change the import everytime you've change the name of your class. From the code you've shown to us, in the class `ImportFilesr` your constructor is `IniFiles` wich is different from the name of your class.